# Extension method instead of Null Object pattern

Tags: c#, .net, null, extension-methods

I'm wondering to using extension method to avoid checking for null in hierarchy.
The example:

```
// GetItems(), GetFirstOrDefault(), GetProduct(), GetIDProduct() are extension methods like:
public static SomeType GetSomeProperty( this XYZ obj ) {
    if ( object.ReferenceEquals( obj, null ) ) { return default( SomeType ); }
    return obj.SomeProperty;
}

// the code with extension methods
Guid? idProduct = this.Invoice.GetItems().GetFirstOrDefault().GetProduct().GetIDProduct();
// instead of
Guid? idProduct = null;
Invoice invoice = this.Invoce;
if ( null != invoice ) {
    InvoiceItems items = invoice.Items;
    if ( null != items && items.Count > 0 ) {
        InvoiceItem item = items[0];
        if ( null != item ) {
            idProduct = item.IDProduct();
        }
    }
}
```

I know, there is available Null Object pattern, but the solution with this type of extension methods looks better.

Do you think, this solution is good or bad (because bad/good design, lucidity, whatever else)?

Please vote "Good" or "Bad" and why do you think so.
Posts are flaged as community.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just do it sanely:

```
Guid? idProduct = null;
Invoice invoice = this.Invoce;

if (invoice != null && 
    invoice.Items != null &&
    invoice.Items.Count > 0 &&
    invoice.Items[0] != null) 
{
   idProduct = invoice.Items[0].IDProduct();
}
```

Comment: And do you know why is the solution with extension method bad? Or do you have "only" feeling? ( No offence, the feeling are sometimes better mentor than exact arguments ).

It looks cool for me, but I'm not sure, there is some disadvantage.

Comment: Its an abuse of extension methods and a codesmell in my opinion, especially with what you are trying to do only taking 4 lines (your example was needlessly complex)

Comment: This argument can be used also against the Null Object patter, right?
Thanks for the opinion, this is exactly type of answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Aside from anything else, it's pretty obvious that Jonathan's code won't go bang. You have to know that the others are extension methods which will work with null input otherwise. Also because there are only extension methods (not properties) you end up with non-idiomatic code.

Answer (score 1):

This [breaks the semantics](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2008/07/c-extension-methods-and-null-references.html) of an instance method. Extension methods look like instance methods to the callers, and as such should *behave* like them. When you break semantics like this, the code will be harder to understand and maintain, its behavior will surprise most developers.

Answer (score 1):

**I vote this as "not-interested-in-that-solution".**

I'm fine with a Null-Object-Pattern for my entity model classes.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that struck me when reading this code was

```
GetFirstOrDefault().GetProduct()
```

It breaks two idioms: 1) using `Get` style methods as noted by Jon, and 2) "unhiding" the abstraction provided by Null Object. The `OrDefault` engages me as a reader of your code and makes me think about `null` where

```
GetFirst().GetProduct()
```

would not. And yes, one of the points of Null Object and your extension method alternative are to unburden the reader and/or maintainer. Or else why do either?

Answer (score 0):

One limitation with Java and .net is that there's nothing which clearly identifies whether a storage location of reference type should be regarded semantically as *holding* an object's value, versus *identifying* an object (from the computer's perspective, of course, all such storage locations do the latter).  Nonetheless, there are some types (like `String`) for which a storage location would normally be regarded as holding a value, and others (like `StringBuilder`) for which a storage location would be regarded as identifying an object upon which operations should be performed.

Were it not for the `struct` constraint on `Nullable<T>`, and if class types could specify that instance members should run (with `this` being null) when invoked on a null object, I would regard that as an excellent pattern for some types.  While it's generally not possible to sensibly specify a default value for a mutable class type, for many immutable types it would be entirely reasonable to have sensible default behavior (e.g. `default(string).Length` could return zero).  Unfortunately, .net languages do not have a means of specifying that properties and methods should be usable on null objects, but at least extension methods can help a little in that direction.